# What happens when a tmpfs volume is full and swap is full? Is Linux's OOM-killer involved?

Tags: linux, swap, tmpfs, out-of-memory

I understand that if a persistent / disk-based volume is full, files need to be explicitly deleted to free up space before more can be added.

Further, I understand that if memory is exhausted, the Linux kernel's OOM-killer will begin terminating processes in order to free up memory.

As tmpfs is an in-memory file-system, it occurred to me that there may or may not be some cross-over between regular volume behaviour and Linux's memory management.

Does the OOM-killer automatically start removing files based on some criteria (either by default or with configuration)?

Or is tmpfs in all respects just like other file-systems when it is full (and swap is full)?

#### EDIT #1

I've read [Out of Swap - What happens?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/135114/out-of-swap-what-happens) but it doesn't even mention "tmpfs" which is what this question is about.

#### EDIT #2

I've read [What sets the size of tmpfs? What happens when its full?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205174/what-sets-the-size-of-tmpfs-what-happens-when-its-full) and this answers the question well enough that I think my question is practically a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @Bichoy, but my question is specifically about tmpfs + OOM-killer.

Comment: Good .. just checking :) I had a question about tmpfs earlier this week (what sets the size of tmps? what happens when its full?), and the answer I got is that it acts the same as any another application using the memory ... So out-of memory behavior should be similar, to the best of my understanding.

Comment: @Bichoy ah, okay. Your question actually does answer my question. OOM killer is not involved at all. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205174/what-sets-the-size-of-tmpfs-what-happens-when-its-full

Answer (score 2):

No, the OOM-killer is not involved at all. There is no magic. tmpfs just behaves like any other file-system: [What sets the size of tmpfs? What happens when its full?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205174/what-sets-the-size-of-tmpfs-what-happens-when-its-full)